# Temporarily ignore pk constraints whilst performing an update query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014-express

I am in the process of transferring data from an old database into a new one.  The table structures between the two are somewhat different, but I have taken care to ensure that there are no serious data type mismatches and in the main the process has been working well.

Over the years the original database (which had auto increment id columns) had had rows deleted, so when transferred to the new database had just auto incremental id columns remained there would have been serious mismatches, so I added, at least as a temporary measure , columns that would hold the values of the old primary keys to enable me to run various update queries and rebalance the data.

The one thing I did not, foolishly, think through perhaps as carefully as I should was the matter of tables where the primary key was an amalgamation of two fields.

So to my question.

I have the following query;

```
UPDATE FishTrackerPro.dbo.LandingDetails
SET LandingId =  lh.LandingId 
FROM LandingHeaders lh 
WHERE LandingDetails.LandingId = lh.OriginalLandingId
```

If run as is it will fail with the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_LandingDetails'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.LandingDetails'. The duplicate key value
>   is (918, 42).

The primary key is made up of the fields LandingId and ProductId.

Fine, that makes perfect sense, but if it were to run fully then any violations would be removed.  So is there a way to run this query telling the query compiler to ignore any violations and just complete it?

Comment: Doesn't have ms-sql DEFERRABLE constraints ?

Comment: @joop  Sorry I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by that.

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/q/5300307/2235885

Comment: Look at `ALTER INDEX xxx ON xxx DISABLE`. Never tried, it might work. Afterwards do `ALTER INDEX xxx ON xxx
REBUILD`. If it works I'll post as an answer. GL.

Comment: @hoop I don't think that applies to SQL Server tbh.