# Oracle: When are constraints checked?

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, constraints

In my understanding constraints should generally be checked at the end of a transaction.

So, in a simple example where we have one table `A` with the only column `P`, which is its primary key, and a table `B` with the primary key `P` and the foreign key `F` on `A.P`, the following should work (on empty tables):

```
begin

    insert into B (P, F)
    values (1, 1);
    insert into A (P)
    values (1);

    commit;
end;
```

However, Oracle gives me the error (in German):

```
[23000][2291] ORA-02291: Integritäts-Constraint (DATABASE.AB_constraint) verletzt - übergeordneter Schlüssel nicht gefunden
ORA-06512: in Zeile 3
Position: 0
```

which translates to *Integrity-constraint violated - referenced key not found*. If I reverse the order

```
begin

    insert into A (P)
    values (1);
    insert into B (P, F)
    values (1, 1);

    commit;
end;
```

it works fine. Are constraints not validated at the end of a transaction in Oracle? And if so, is there any way of enforcing this behaviour?

In the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT117) it's stated that (following the A**C**ID properties)

> [t]he transaction takes the database from one consistent state to another consistent state.

So one could expect that the states in between don't necessarily have to be consistent. This certainly applies for the example Oracle provides: Money is transfered from one account to another one, whilst in between the total sum of money doesn't match up (isn't consistent), as the money got removed from one account, but not yet added to the other one. So why doesn't it seem to be the same for foreign key constraints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *And if so, is there any way of enforcing this behaviour*

Yes, there it is. It's called a deferred constraint.

If a constraint is deferred it is checked at the end of the transaction, rather when the statement is executed.

```
alter table some_table
   add constraint fk_something 
   foreign key (some_column) references other_table(pk_column)
   deferrable initially deferred;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5300418/330315) for an explanation on the difference between `initially deferred` and `initially immediate`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly define a constraint as a [deferred constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm), constraints are checked when the rows are inserted into the table.

The data is not actually visible outside until the transaction is committed, but data integrity is checked step-by-step.

Comment: One could argue though that the rows are inserted into the table at the end of the transaction - at least their _persisted_ at the end of the transaction. Also, as Oracles example proofed, data integrity is not always checked step-by-step.

Comment: Foreign key constraints can be deferred to be checked at the end of the transaction  in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

One way around this would be *defer* the related constraint within the block, like:

```
begin
    execute immediate 'set constraint ab_constraint deferred';
    insert into B (P, F) values (1, 1);
    insert into A (P) values (1);
    execute immediate 'set constraint ab_constraint immediate';
    commit;
end;
```

Comment: This gives me the error (roughly translated) _Non defferable constraint can't be deferred_

Comment: @MetaColon: this requires your column to have been defined as *deferrable*.

Comment: I found that out by the answer linked by @a_horse_with_no_name, but thanks for the hint.